# Pass array as parameter to php script

Tags: php

I want to run php script and pass parameters to it. Parameter are in array.

I json_encode array:

```
$bot = array(
   'timing' => '* * * * *',
   'path' => '/sompath/'
);

$bot = json_encode($bot);
```

And send it to script:

```
exec('nohup php script.php "' . $bot . '" > /bot.log 2>&1 &');
```

But then, in script, I don' receive arguments:

```
print_r($argv[1]); // {path:/sompath/,frequency:*
```

Looks like special symbols like asterisks are not parsed and break json.

**How do I pass array to another script and be shure that all arguments are kept?**

Comment: Why you are using json_encode function twice?

Comment: sorry mistake making example

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass the json data as a string you should first escape it:

```
$bot = array(
   'timing' => '* * * * *',
   'path' => '/sompath/'
);

$bot = json_encode($bot);
$bot=escapeshellarg($bot);
```

And then on the receiving script:

```
print_r(json_decode($argv[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

It was simple. Should use `urlencode` to pass json correctly.

```
exec('nohup php script.php "' . urlencode($bot) . '" > /bot.log 2>&1 &');
```

And then, in in script.php:

```
$params = urldecode($argv[1]);
$params = json_decode($params, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't send arguments using `nohup`. By the way, this code is working for me!

```
$arg1 = escapeshellarg("Hello World");
$ouput = shell_exec("php file.php {$arg1} >/dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

file.php

```
$argument = $argv[1];
```